# Coupon code Magento 1.9.x bug

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.9

I have two users: A and B 
**A**: checkout with Paypal
**B**: checkout with COD
They apply coupon code: XXXXABC

In Admin Setting:
**Uses per Coupon**: set to **1**.

However,
user A in **Payment Review** (Paypal Review)
use B in **Order Review**.
User A and B click **Place Order** at the same time (or late seconds). Both of them applied XXXXABC coupon code. But, **Uses per Coupon**: set to **1** in Admin.

**Expect result**: Only one user can apply this coupon code.
Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a bug. User A and User B individually has taken benefits of coupon code XXXXABC just once as per the settings you have configured. However it would be considered as a bug if they try to apply the same coupon code again and got success. That means one can use a coupon code only once.
Hence in your case both users used code once.
*For example*:-
**First chance** (User A, B, D uses code XXXXABC and got success)
**Second chance** (User C, A, D, E uses code XXXXABC and only users C, E got success as they are using first time. Where users A, D got failure as they already have applied in the first chance)

I hope my comments will clear the concepts much in depth.

Comment: What do you think about **Uses per Coupon: set to 1**? I think this issue is related to Paypal. If user A and user B checkout with COD, only one user can apply coupon.